# Mongo Db Connect to html

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb

I am trying to use html css and js to connect to mongodb atlas and i tried following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhqOp1Dkuso) tutorial but it does not work for me so can you suggest and appropriate tutorial or give me some sample code to work with. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you specify what is the error and also please add your code.

Comment: I dont really get an error but instead what happens is that my document is inserted and has nothing except this:

    _id:ObjectId("62fa3fe926b9a1ccf8cbdc07")
    __v:0

But it does not show my entering